# Please solve these errors. I'm using dev++ compiler

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, inheritance, operator-overloading

Kindly tell me what's wrong with the code. It is showing many errors. The error statements and problem statement is given below:

1. First error is in the overloaded dereference operator. It says pmemory was not declared in this scope.
2. 2nd error is in the main function where I use

   ```
    ptrFloat ptr1 = &var1;
   ```

it shows error "conversion from 'Float' to non-scalar type 'ptrFloat' requested".

3. And in the next line of above mention statement save error..
4. in next line it show that (no match for operator <<) .
5. and in the very next line it show the same error as above.(no match for operator).
6. And at last it show again the same error that (no match for operator)

The question statement is given below:

> Remember fmem_top is an index to fmemory which points to the next available place where a float value can be stored. And pmem_top is the similer index to pmemory.
>
> Create a class called  Float . We’ll use it to model numbers of type  float that are stored in fmemory instead of real memory. The only instance data in  Float is its own “address”; that is, the index where its  float value is stored in  fmemory. Call this instance variable addr. Class  Float also needs two member functions. The first is a one-argument constructor to initialize the  Float with a  float value. This constructor stores the  float value in the element of  fmemory pointed to by  fmem_top , and stores the value of fmem_top in addr . This is similar to how the compiler and linker arrange to store an ordinary variable in real memory. The second member function is the overloaded  & operator. It simply returns the pointer (really the index, type  int ) value in  addr .
>
> Create a second class called  ptrFloat . The instance data in this class holds the address(index) in  pmemory where some other address (index) is stored. A member function initializes this “pointer” with an  int index value. The second member function is the overloaded * (dereference, or “contents of”) operator. Its operation is a tad more complicated.
>
> It obtains the address from  pmemory , where its data, which is also an address, is stored. It then uses this new address as an index into  fmemory to obtain the float value pointed to by its address data.

```
float& ptrFloat::operator*()
{
 return fmemory[pmemory[addr]];
}






#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
class Float
{
protected:
    float *fmem_top;
    float **addr;
    float fmemory[10];
public:
    Float(float a)
    {
        
        fmem_top=fmemory;
        addr=&fmem_top;
        *fmem_top=a;
        fmem_top++;
    }
    Float operator & ()
    {
        return *fmem_top;
    }
};

class ptrFloat: public Float
{
private:
    int *pmem_top;
    int  pmemory[10];
public:
    ptrFloat(int abc) : Float(abc)
    {
        pmem_top=pmemory;
        *pmem_top=abc;
        pmem_top++;
    }
    
    
    ptrFloat operator * ()
    {
        return fmemory[pememory[addr]];
    }
};

int main ()
{
Float var1 = 1.234;
Float var2 = 5.678;


ptrFloat ptr1 = &var1;
ptrFloat ptr2 = &var2;

cout<<"*ptr1 = "<< *ptr1;
cout<<"*ptr2 = "<< *ptr2;

*ptr1 = 7.123;
*ptr2 = 8.456;

cout<<"*ptr1 = "<< *ptr1;
cout<<"*ptr2 = "<< *ptr2;
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of erros and is not explicit what your question is. You shouldn't just ask for somebody to correct your code.

Comment: Also the title is dreadful. How exactly is this question supposed to help somebody else one day? How are they even supposed to find it?

Comment: use the edit link to edit your question title. Your question title must describe your problem in short.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The first error is a typo you wrote *pememory*.

The second error appears because you didn't code any transformation between **Float** and **ptrFloat**.

You should add a copy constructor to **Float**:

```
Float(const Float& a) : Float(*a.fmem_top) {}
```

And then a conversion constructor to **ptrFloat**:

```
ptrFloat(Float a) : Float(a) {
    pmem_top=pmemory;
    *pmem_top=abc;
    pmem_top++;
}
```

PS: your code has a lot of problems. I don't really get what you are trying to do, but, for instance, you can't have *float* typed variables as array subscripts.

Comment: please read the post again i have edited it. now i have wrote the question statement. i will be thankful if you rewrite the code according to statement.. i need help.

Comment: @NoumanTariq: people are willing to help here, i.e. they suggest fixes and you do them. You'll learn better that way anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going on here, but this is what Clang has to say:

```
prog.cc:33:48: error: array subscript is not an integer
  ptrFloat operator*() { return fmemory[pmemory[addr]]; }
                                               ^~~~~
```

There's a typo in the line here - you'd written `pememory`. But `addr` is a `float**`.

```
prog.cc:40:12: error: no viable conversion from 'Float' to 'ptrFloat'
  ptrFloat ptr1 = &var1;
           ^      ~~~~~
```

`ptrFloat` is a class derived from `Float`, not a `Float*`.

What's your intent with this code?

---

As an aside, the `clang` compiler has great and helpful error messages. If you don't/can't install `clang` on your computer - I think it's a pfaff to set it up on Windows, I don't know - you can quickly test your code on an online compiler such as Wandbox and see if `clang`'s output gives better clues. Here's your code running there - I had to strip out `conio.h` and `getch` as they're Windows-only: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4iCa61Rqysqc7Lpl

Comment: yeah.. that's the main thing that i could not understand. actually it's statement is too big and much confusing. that's why i can't understand. can you rewrite the code?

Comment: I can't rewrite your `Float` class because I'm not sure what it does or what it's meant to do, for a start - also I do have other things to do this afternoon :)

Comment: bro now i have edited my post and write the exact statement of the code.. i will be thankful if you rewrite the code according to statement. i know i have made many mistakes in my code. but i need your help..

Comment: I'm upvoting Jack's answer in the hope that he does not do your homework for you, Nouman.